# c++ cli ref class array converted to pointer

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, interop, metadata

I am trying to write a managed wrapper class in order to perform interop and conversion for a native class. I wrote something similar to this in my interop library;

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public ref class MyClass {
    public:
        static void MyMethod(double myArray[]);
    }
}
```

However when I reference this library from my C# application, the interface has changed. If I F12 on the class in C# I get the regenerated interface `MyClass [from metadata]` which looks like this;

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class MyClass {
        public static void MyMethod(double myArray*);
    }
}
```

Why did the compiler convert the array into a pointer? How can I get the compiler to correctly expose this argument as an array rather than a pointer?

If I want to use the class in this way then I would have to get a pointer to the managed array in an unsafe context, which I don't want to do.

#### Update

When I do `typeof(double[])` in C# I get;

```
{Name = "Double[]" FullName = "System.Double[]"}
    Assembly: {mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "System.Double[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    Attributes: Public | Sealed | Serializable
    BaseType: {Name = "Array" FullName = "System.Array"}
    ...}
```

So I understand the comments suggesting that I need a `System.Array`. However, my question still stands, how do I declare a `System.Double[]` array in the interop class? Simply putting `MyMethod(System::Double[] myArray)` doesn't work...

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe I am correct. It's converted to a pointer, because the array in your C++ doesn't utilize `System.Array` for arrays, which C# does and in that case it just expects a pointer to the data instead.

Comment: If so, maybe you could replace the `double[]` argument by some .net array type. It should be possible to use such a type in C++/CLI

Comment: My problem is that `System.Array` is typeless. I want the argument to be interpreted as a `double[]` not a `System.Array`.

Comment: I understand that in the native world, arrays and pointers are synonymous. However, there is such thing as a managed `double[]` and it can be passed in an argument, so how do I get the ref class to expose it as a `double []` instead of a `double*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cli::array<double>^` which is a managed array. The `double something[]` syntax will define an unmanaged array, which decays to a pointer in metadata.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbydz1t.aspx) for reference.

Comment: Thank you Lucas, that is more like what I am looking for. However, I tried replacing it and I get the message "a C++/CLI array type is not allowed here". It allows `std::array` but I don't thin that is what I am looking for...

Comment: I tried using `std::array`. I have to specify the rank, such as `array<double, 1>`. This still doesn't work as I get a different error "incomplete type is not allowed".

Comment: @Steztric Are you sure you didn't omit the final `^`? You may also try to drop the `cli::`. Unfortunately I don't have a compiler handy at the moment so I can't check myself. `std::array` is something entirely different, you can't use that from C#.